# Efficiently finding non zero numbers from a large matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 512 x 512 x 112 matrix with three kind of values : zeroes, non zeroes and NaN.

How can I get the indices of the non zero values of the matrix efficiently (without using loop)?

Comment: actually `[idx1 idx2 idx3] = ind2sub(size(my_mat), find(my_mat));` should do the work, but i doubt that because the size of your matrix is quite big

Answer (score 2):

The comment from @scmg is the way to go- Matlab's linear logical indexing is a way to avoid looping over the elements; it only takes 1.2 sec on my PC. Here is a working example:

```
rng(8675309) %jenny number for consistency
x=randn([512,512,112]); % make random matrix
x(x<0)=NaN; % set some elements to NaN
x(x<4)=0; % set some elements to zero
[i1,i2,i3]=ind2sub(size(x),find(x>0)); %use find+ind2sub to avoid loop
scatter3(i1,i2,i3)% plot results for fun
```

Comment: because how you defined your matrix already limited the result. I tried your code with `x(x>1) = NaN;` and `x(x>4) = 0;` instead, and my Matlab was busy for more than 30 sec until i pressed Ctrl + C (+_+!) --- or just use `x(1,1,1) = 0; x(512, 512, 512) = NaN;`, my Matlab was busy for about 20 sec and quit itself (run out of 8GB-RAM?)!!!

Comment: @scmg I don't quite get what you mean. This seems to run quickly enough for me (just a second or two). Is there a reason this approach should be slow?

Comment: i meant with the code you posted, it also ran well in my Matlab, but if i change line 3 and line 4 to `x(1,1,1) = 0; x(512, 512, 512) = NaN;`, then it was very slow on my laptop, even that Matlab quits itself after 20sec busy, i'm not sure if it happens to you ... and i thought the problem was that with your code, i got a result of just about ~ 10000 indices

Comment: @scmg Odd. I'm not sure what the difference would be. I agree the array is very large, but the `find` function seems to get through it quickly for me.

Comment: @scmg: Really weird; the x matrix should be only 235Mb, whats your system configuration?  I was using Matlab 2013b 64-bit on Win7.  Changing the matrix to make most of the entries non-zero increases the calculation time (to 1.4s in my case), but dont try to send the data to `scatter3`, plotting 10M vs 1k points is too much.  Also, the command `x(512,512,512)` will try to make matlab add >100k more entries to x: `size(x) =[512,512,112]` that will cause some lag as well.