# Vectorizing a parallel FOR loop across multiple dimensions MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

Please correct me if there are somethings unclear in this question. I have two matrices `pop`, and `ben` of 3 dimensions. Call these dimensions as `c,t,w` . I want to repeat the exact same process I describe below for all of the `c` dimensions, without using a for loop as that is slow. For the discussion below, fix a value of the dimension `c`, to explain my thinking, later I will give a MWE. So when c is fixed I have a 2D matrix with dimension `t,w`.

Now I repeat the entire process (coming below!) for all of the w dimension.
If the value of u is zero, then I find the next non zero entry in this same t dimension. I save both this entry as well as the corresponding t index. If the value of u is non zero, I simply store this value and the corresponding t index. Call the index as i - note i would be of dimension `(c,t,w)`. The last entry of every `u(c,:,w)` is guaranteed to be non zero.

*Example* if the `u(c,:,w)` vector is [ 3 0 4 2 0 1], then the corresponding i values are `[1,3,3,4,6,6]`. 
Now I take these entries and define a new 3d array of dimension `(c,t,w)` as follows. I take my B array and do the following what is not a correct syntax but to explain you: `B(c,t,w)/u(c,i(c,t,w),w)`. Meaning I take the `B` values and divide it by the `u` values corresponding to the non zero indices of u from i that I computed.

*For the above example,* the denominator would be `[3,4,4,2,1,1]`. I hope that makes sense!!

QUESTION:
To do this, as this process simply repeats for all `c`, I can do a very fast vectorizable calculation for a single c. But for multiple c I do not know how to avoid the for loop. I don't knw how to do vectorizable calculations across dimensions. 
Here is what I did, where c_size is the dimension of c.

```
for c=c_size:-1:1
    uu=squeeze(pop(c,:,:)) ; % EXTRACT A 2D MATRIX FROM pop.
    BB=squeeze(B(c,:,:)) ; % EXTRACT A 2D MATRIX FROM B
    ii = nan(size(uu));  % Start with all nan values
    [dum_row, ~] = find(uu);  % Get row indices of non-zero values
    ii(uu ~= 0) = dum_row;     % Place row indices in locations of non-zero values
    ii = cummin(ii, 1, 'reverse');  % Column-wise cumulative minimum, starting from bottomi
    dum_i = ii+(time_size+1).*repmat(0:(scenario_size-1), time_size+1, 1);  % Create linear index
    ben(c,:,:) = BB(dum_i)./uu(dum_i);
    i(c,:,:) = ii ;
    clear dum_i dum_row uu BB ii
end
```

The central question is to avoid this for loop.

Related questions:

1. [Vectorizable FIND function with if statement MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56363677/vectorizable-find-function-with-if-statement-matlab/56370830#56370830)
2. [Efficiently finding non zero numbers from a large matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930002/efficiently-finding-non-zero-numbers-from-a-large-matrix?rq=1)

   3. [Vectorizable FIND function with if statement MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56363677/vectorizable-find-function-with-if-statement-matlab?rq=1)

Comment: How much too slow is your loop version of the code? What kind of speed up do you need? Note that loops are not slow in MATLAB. They were 15 years a go and people still hold on to that concept for some reason. Your loop will likely be much faster if you remove the `clear` statement.

Comment: @CrisLuengo please see the linked answer. The factor of improvement I got for the case of a single c (i.e., 2D array) with a vectorizable statement instead of a for loop was two orders of magnitude. 
I will remove the clear statements, okay. But I still need a vectorizable and logical indexing help, as this loop is run about 1e+5 times in my code.

Comment: That code is 100 faster not because the loop was removed, but because the logic of the code was simplified. I can show you many examples on SO where the loop code was faster than all attempts at vectorization because vectorization often involves making the logic more complex, or increasing the amount of intermediate memory used. 15 years ago those tradeoffs were worth it because loops were slow. Now they are no longer worth it. My point: ask for a way to speed up your code **if it has been shown to be the bottleneck**, don’t ask to remove the loop.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Do you have any suggestions other than the comment about clear you asked to speedup the solution of my question?